# Geoserver ECQL LIKE Operator in CSS Style Results in Incorrect Legend

Tags: geoserver

I'm attempting to create a geoserver style that will alter a fill based on the first letter (or letters) of a category name, using the CSS styling syntax.  When Geoserver generates the legend based off the following style, it's seemingly creating a legend entry for every permutation of the three style rules.  Any idea why the LIKE operator causes this behavior while the = operator does not?

[geoserver legend example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63mtK.png)

```
/* @title 100 Year */
[cat LIKE 'A%'] {
  fill: "#FB4852";
}

/* @title 500 Year */
[cat LIKE 'X5%'] {
  fill: "#7D57A5";
}

/* @title Unspecified */
[cat LIKE 'D%'] {
  fill: "#FFFD38";
}
```

Comment: because that is the way CSS works, the optimiser can't (or doesn't bother) to tell that those filters can't overlap